# autocomplete using jquery shows bullet points with no values in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4, Ajax and Jquery to auto-complete search field. I am unable to show search result. All I get to see is the list of bullet points with no search data in it. **I am not sure how to check if data is really passed to the view?** I did console.log (ui) but no result on console

Below is the screenshot showing search bar with bullet points results.

[image: screenshot of search bar showing bullet points]

## jquery search code

```
 $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
  source    : '{{ url("/admin/users/autocomplete") }}',
  minlength :1,
  autofocus : true,
  select:function (e,ui){
    console.log(ui);
    alert(ui);
  }
});
```

## input field code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%; display:none;" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" placeholder="Enter username..." >
```

display none property in input field changes to display:block when first name is selected from drop down. that is not the issue if that thought crosses ur mind.

## Updated - output from the url /admin/users/autocomplete?term=...

```
[{"id":6,"name":"Lulu"},{"id":14,"name":"Luis"}]
```

Now I am in much better state, all I need is data to be inserted into those empty results. below are the images with update html state and screenshot of inspect element screen if it helps find bug:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide a link to an example or the output of /admin/users/autocomplete (at least a part where we can see the structure there)
Have you added the stylesheet for jquery autocomplete?

Comment: @SimonEritsch I have not added any style for autocomplete and I dont know what css classes to override. I will add the output of /admin/users/autocomplete in my question. pls chk updated question

Comment: Most likely either a problem with text color or z-index. Use your browser dev tools to find out more, or give us a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @CBroe yes, but I am unable to reach those bullet points, it happens in flash I see .ui-autocomplete-input which I set to z-index of 1000 !important and I see  .ui-helper-hidden-accessible which I set it to display:none bcoz it says you have 5 results, which I dont wont to show

Comment: I think there is no data returned to the view. I am unable to print it to console.log or so. How do I verify if autocomplete data is returned or not?

Answer (score 0):

I just split the action of collecting data and serving it to source of auto-complete. below is my code:

```
  var searchdata = [];
  var select2 = $('#searchfield').val();
  $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url  :  "{{url('/admin/users/autocomplete')}}",
          data :  {type : id, type_val : select2},
        }).done(function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
          $.each(data, function( index, value ) 
          {
            searchdata.push(data[index].firstname);
          });
          $("#searchfield").autocomplete(
          {
            source    : searchdata,
            minlength :1,
            autofocus : true
          });       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery autocomplete expects a specificly formatted Array.
Try changing your autocomplete output to something like:

```
[
   {"data":6,"value":"Lulu"},
   {"data":14,"value":"Luis"}
]
```

So just change the name of the object keys for every element from id, name to data, value